# Jenkins Could not find artifact from pom repositories

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, pom.xml

Have mentioned 2 different repositories in pom like following, for multiple dependencies from different artifactories.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jfrog-repo1</id>
        <url>https://my.jfrog.artifactory.cmpny.com/artifactory/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>nexus-repo1</id>
        <url>https://my.nexus.artifactory.cmpny.com/artifactory/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This works when I build the project locally, but doesn't work on the Jenkins setup by my company. Somehow it is searching for dependency1 in repo2.

> Failed to execute goal on project my-project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my.company:my-project:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.my.cmpny.newproject:my-dependency:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in snapshots (https://my.nexus.artifactory.cmpny.com/artifactory/snapshots).

This also works in another projects where we mention any one repository in pom.

Comment: I recommend to configure different repositories in on of your repository managers and configuration this only one in your settings.xml file ... Furthermore keep in mind that by default SNAPSHOT's will be deleted after an amount of time

Comment: @khmarbaise no changes required in settings.xml as I as mentioned "This works when I build the project locally"

Comment: Maybe you your Jenkins there is a settings.xml (config file provider plugin)..

Comment: I have made no changes in settings xml at local, should work at Jenkins too.